# Prior to the implementation of closures, were all functions declared in the global context?

Tags: javascript

Closures [were introduced](https://youtu.be/aX3ZABCdC38?t=381) in [JavaScript 1.2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/New_in_JavaScript/1.2) (Netscape Navigator 4.0, June 1997) and standardised in ECMAScript 3.0.

[image]

Prior to this, were all user-defined functions at the top level, in the global context?

Comment: I don't see any mention of closures there.

Comment: Are you talking about this: **You can now nest functions within functions.**

Comment: If you couldn't nest functions before this, than where else could functions have been defined other than at top level?

Comment: Nowhere I can think of! I want to confirm this was true.

Comment: Note that nested functions are not necessarily the same as closures. It depends on whether the nested function captures the local variables of the parent function.

Comment: From 1997... not many people will be able to answer this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, yes. Until Netscape Navigator was released on June 11th 1997, only top-level functions were supported, and by almost-implication, no closures.

Confirmed by [Brendan Eich](https://twitter.com/03d5d0a1/status/1235353036576391168?s=20).

Comment: …and there I thought the design of the language included closures from the very beginning. OOP might have seemed more important though.